# Listen to all UPD Requests on a specfic Network Adapter

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

I use Socket in C# to Listen to UPD Requests

```
var bindIp = IpAddress.Parse("0.0.0.");
var ipLocalEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(bindIp, PORT_TO_LISTEN_TO);
socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
socket.Bind(ipLocalEndPoint);
```

Problem is, when I use anthoer IP as "0.0.0.0", I don't get Broadcast Messages.

But I want to restrict the Soket to one specific Network Adapter, not to a Ip. Is this possible?

Edited:

Or at least, is it possible to detect from wich Adapter a UPD Request is comming from?

Comment: Use Socket.ReceiveFrom method, no matter what overloaded method you use, the endpoint is stored. That is the source IP that sent you the datagram.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention to the fact that IP is not the same as a network adapter. A network adapter can have multiple IPs. The opposite is also possible, e.g. with trunks.
When you `bind()`, then the network stack decides which network interface to use, based on interface's existing IP addresses. If you use 0.0.0.0 then binding is done to all interfaces (if you `connect()` instead, binding is done based on network stack routing table).
Anyway: if you want to get broadcast messages, you have to bind to 0.0.0.0, as otherwise you will only get traffic related to a specific IP.

Comment: I know that a Adapter can have multiple Ip's. But Is it not possible to say "use only data from this Adapter?". Or can I filter later the recieved Data?

Comment: You can bind to an IP that is used by the given interface. Then you can set this socket (interface, actually) into **promiscuous mode**. In C you use `ioctl()` for this; in C# this will probably be  DeviceIoControl (https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/windows/desktop/aa363219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: If I use

     socket.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, BitConverter.GetBytes(1), null);

I got a Exception